# Запятая перед КАК

Tags: пунктуация

Преклоняюсь перед всеми! Меня дико — или как это можно назвать? — заинтересовал один вопрос. Например, «Ты говоришь, как моя мама». Правильно ли я считаю, что здесь следует поставить запятую? Насколько я понял, если имеется значение сравнения (это всё-таки сравнительный оборот), то необходимо ставить.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это спорный случай. Не один Вы, [[@Tagirix](/users/3739/tagirix)](/users/3739/tagirix), терзаетесь сомнениями. "*Моя девушка одевается как Дженнифер Лопес* — здесь нужна запятая? С одной стороны, налицо сравнение. С другой стороны, сказуемое не имеет смысла без оборота с как: смысл не в том, что девушка одевается, а в том, что она одевается как Дженнифер Лопес, значит, не нужна запятая?" ([Пахомов В. "В интернет-переписке главное — скорость, а не правила правописания" / беседу вела К. Туркова // Московские новости](http://www.mn.ru/society_edu/20120710/322512539.html)).

Comment: "Ты говоришь, как моя мама" означает "ты говоришь то же (такими же словами), что и моя мама". Здесь, скорее, имеется в виду не особенности произношения, а содержание речи, поэтому по смыслу  оборот близок к изъяснительному предложению. "Моя девушка одевается как Дженнифер Лопес — здесь не нужна запятая. Это именно сравнительный оборот, тесно связанный со сказуемым и входящий в 
основное сообщение.

Answer (score 0):

Запятая нужна, но это, скорее, неполное придаточное сравнительное предложение: "Ты говоришь (так), как (говорит) моя мама".

Слово "дико" не стоит употреблять в  тексте нейтрального стиля, оно уместно в разговорной речи для выражения особой экспрессии. Лучше сказать "очень заинтересовал".

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ ОТ 23.07.14

Думаю, что это сложный случай, где возможны два решения:
1) Ты говоришь как моя мама. Сравнительный оборот в роли обстоятельства в простом предложении. 
2) Ты говоришь,  как моя мама. Это неполное сравнительное предложение: Ты говоришь,  как  (говорит) моя мама.

Что касается терминов  «сравнение, тождество, уподобление», то  я для себя составила особую схему их употребления, которую условно можно описать так:

1. СРАВНИТЕЛЬНЫЙ оборот: a как b.  Предмет (признак, действие) названы два раза и сравниваются между собой.  Тропинка, как змея, извивается между деревьями. Но:  Тропинка извивается как змея.
2. Оборот со значением ТОЖДЕСТВА: a = b.   Два тождественных названия одного предмета.  Как истинный художник, Пушкин видел поэтическое начало в самых простых вещах (значение причины). Но: Как художник  Лев Толстой гениален (в качестве).
3. Обороты со значением УПОДОБЛЕНИЯ: как а.     Предмет (признак, действие) названы ОДИН РАЗ. Обороты со значением уподобления  обособляются реже, чем обороты со значением сравнения (при достаточной распространенности и позиции, удобной для обособления). Дверь широко распахнулась, точно от порыва ветра. Косматые вершины сосен бились и метались, как в безумном танце. В лицо пахнуло, точно из погреба, сырым холодом. Но: Словно белою косынкой подвязалася сосна. На улице жарко как летом. Стреляет как из пушки гром.

Comment: Полностью согласен насчёт употребления слово "дико". Но я правильно считаю, что тут присутствует сравнение? :)

Comment: Да, это значение сравнения, но сравнение может быть выражено сравнительным оборотом или сравнительным придаточным предложением (полным или неполным). Вот пример сравнительного оборота: Ты, как моя мама, любишь все объяснять.

Comment: Может, тут лучше так: "Ты, как и моя мама, любишь всё объяснять". Всё-таки сочетание .., как и .., куда чаще употребляется, не правда ли?

Comment: Да, пожалуй, здесь больше подходит союз КАК И.

Comment: Благозвучнее :)

Answer (score 0):

Запятая после союза как ставится,  если оборот обозначает уподобление (как имеет значение «подобно, как можно заменить другим сравнительным союзом  будто, словно, точно и т. д.).

Ср.: Её уста, как розы, редеют (Пушкин); Внизу, как зеркало стальное, синеют озера струи (Тютчев);

Обороты с как не выделяются запятыми,если оборот имеет значение приравнивания или отождествления.

Ср.: Он любил меня как собственность (Лермонтов).  Он любил меня, считая свой собственностью; Старайтесь смотреть на меня как на пациента, одержимого болезнью, вам ещё неизвестною (Лермонтов).  Старайтесь смотреть на меня, приравнивая меня к пациенту, одержимому болезнью, вам ещё неизвестною;

В данном примере, скорее всего, запятая не нужна, т. к. оборот с "как" имеет значение не сравнения( вряд ли можно сказать подобно маме, словно мама), а отождествления. С другой страны, если все же поставить запятую, то, как мне кажется, смысл поменяется. Получится: говорящий сравнивает особенности разговора собеседника со своей матерью.

А как вы думаете, София?

Comment: Серж, ответ посмотрите в дополнении на моем поле.

Comment: Да, увидел. Очень удобная схема.

Comment: Интересно, что в предложении "Ты говоришь совсем как моя мама" оборот не обособляется при наличии частицы. Также: "Дети рассуждают совсем как взрослые". И по поводу изменения смысла, о котором вы говорили: действительно, можно понять - в качестве моей мамы, как будто ты моя мама. А вот вариант с частицей  имеет однозначный смысл, то есть "теми же словами, в такой же манере, как моя мама".

Answer (score -1):

Запятая не нужна, т. к. союз "как" является уподобительным. Запятая используется только в случае сравнения.

Comment: Да, думаю это так!

Comment: Союз или оборот?